# VBA - Copy / Paste to multiple columns with variable row start (array)

Tags: vba, copy, paste

I'd like to shorten my code by putting multiple columns to one command.
I'm copying formulas from one row but specified columns and want to paste to another sheet in the same wksht. Just the row number is a variable. Maybe do this by an array?
As an example I'm pasting below not working code with only 3 columns.

```
Sub Copy()
Dim LastrowQ As Long
Dim LastrowR As Long
LastrowQ = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
LastrowR = LastrowQ + 1
        
Workbooks(Rep1).Worksheets("Formula").Range("A2, C2:F2, N2, V2:AD2").Copy
*Workbooks(Rep1).Worksheets("Report").Range("A" & LastrowR, "C" & LastrowR & ":F" & LastrowR, "N" & LastrowR, "V" & LastrowR & ":AD" & LastrowR).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas*
    
End Sub
```

**Could you please help to modify the code in paste part as it doesn't work right now?** This would allow to make original code much shorter and hopefully faster.

**What if I'd like to propagate function in second sheet from variable row till the specified row at the same time**? ("A" & LastrowR & ":A" & LastrowS,...)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: It is VBA code.